# What does fulfilled next to Beta Site name in Area 51 mean?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase

What does it mean for a site to have `fulfilled` next to its name in the [All Proposal's beta tab view of Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta)?

The reason I ask is that I moderate Genealogy & Family History and noticed that it is the only site of about a hundred which is "tagged" in that way.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It simply means that you have fulfilled your Area 51 commitment for that site.

From the description when you commit to a site:

> I commit to participate actively in {{SITENAME}} for at least three months, especially during the private beta, and to ask or answer at least ten questions.

The exact specifics of this formula are unknown (supposedly, it gets harder to fulfill a commitment after private beta is over, etc.), but in my experience, posting at least 10 posts within the private beta period is sufficient.